# Печи формата Tower: поиск правильного написания

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, названия

Как правильно написать: печи формата Tower, печи формата "Tower", печи формата tower (имеются в виду печи башенного типа)? Как верно перевести англоязычное слово в систему русского письма? "Тауэр"?

Дополнительные наводки по теме связаны с желанием научиться правильно писать такие выражения, как магазин "у дома", и т. д. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Подскажите, что вы имеете в виду под *дополнительными наводками*?

Comment: Дополнительные ассоциации для тех, кто решился ответить на вопрос)

Answer (score 2):

Корректно: «печи **типа** Tower», либо «печи **типа** "Тауэр"», либо просто «печи башенного **типа**».

При иноязычных названиях кавычки [не ставятся](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2) (подробнее об употреблении кавычек здесь же).

Comment: Спасибо. Только слово "типа" не люблю: оно ассоциируется с разговорным словом "типа", используемым для связки слов в разговорной речи. Считаю, что оно не очень украшает текст. Альтернатива есть? Почему нельзя использовать "формат"?